# It gives an error code after several executions

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that after each execution, 20 of the lowest data are selected and transferred to another sheet.
But when the total number of data is less than 20 after several executions, it gives an error message and the rest of the data is not transferred to the other sheet. I want that after executing the code several times, all the data will be transferred to another sheet and no data will remain.

```
sub cp()
Dim myceell As Range
Dim myrangee As Range



Set myrangee = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("a2:a1000")
myrangee.Interior.Pattern = xlnon
For Each myceell In myrangee
For i = 1 To 20
If myceell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(myrangee, i) Then
myceell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
myceell.Resize(1, 16).Cut Destination:= _
            Worksheets("sheet5").Range("a1").Offset(Worksheets("sheet5").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If

Next
Next myceell
end sub
```

I want that after executing the code several times, all the data will be transferred to another sheet and no data will remain.

Comment: "gives an error message" - what error message, and on which line?

Comment: You need to cut them AFTER the loop as a whole.  You will probably want a new range variable into which you can create a union range.  If you cut while you loop. it will throw the small off as the values are being removed and the small will no longer see them.

Comment: Or you can sort the data on column A and then color and cut the top 20 rows.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write the code so that after leaving the loop, the rest of the data is transferred to another sheet in general?

Comment: Can you tell me how to tell that if you get out of the loop, cut the rest of us to another sheet?

Comment: How can you change the code and sort the rows based on column a and finally transfer 10 of the lowest ones to another sheet each time?

Comment: if your range has unique values you can use `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A1000").Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` then `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A21").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1")`

Comment: This code gives an error
I want the data to be sorted and finally the first 20 data will be cut and transferred to another sheet. And the rest of the rows are moved up so that they are all sorted again.